# Htaccess Redirect only directory root to new page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have thousands of pages on my site among which almost 200 pages are with following format

```
domain.com/prd/cat/name/
```

I want to redirect only the main directory of that url to my new subdomain i.e. `domain.com/prd/ = 310 = sub.domain.com`.
I tried using

```
Redirect 301 /prd/ sub.newpage.com
```

however it breaks all my other pages.Is there a way to execute 301 to ONLY `domain.com/dir/` to subdomain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 possibilities:

**1.** With `RedirectMatch` (using **mod_alias**)

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/prd/$ http://sub.newpage.com
```

**2.** With `RewriteRule` (using **mod_rewrite**)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^prd/$ http://sub.newpage.com [R=301,L]
```